# Can't delete column in pandas dataframe by label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After importing a csv file

```
import pandas as pd
sp = pd.read_csv('ES_M1_askbid_1yr.csv')
sp.columns.str.strip()
sp.drop('K', axis=1, inplace=True)
sp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sp['Date'])
sp.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Now I need to get rid of some columns. I tried it with one column first, 'K'
I get the error: `"['K'] not found in axis"`

I also tried the following variations:

```
sp.drop(['K'], axis=1, inplace=True)
sp.drop(columns=['K'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

If I address the column by position:

```
sp.drop(sp.columns[15], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

then it works, but I would like to call the label, because If I make later changes in the order of the columns it's getting messed up

What could be the problem to delete it by name?

Comment: I'm going to guess that since `sp.columns.str.strip()` doesn't modify your column names in-place, that you'll find `sp.columns[15]` != `'K'`... and the former works because it's using the actual name (leading trailing whitespace characters included etc...)... maybe you meant `sp.columns = sp.columns.str.strip()` ?

Comment: what happens if you `assert sp.columns[15] == 'K'`? i have a hard time believing that pandas is broken. because your code seems fine

Comment: Can you output the column names by calling: list(sp.columns)

Comment: @Nicolas as I said in a comment above... must likely it's a case of expecting `sp.columns.str.strip()` to have operated inplace...

Comment: `sp.columns = sp.columns.str.strip()` is the solution! thank you!

Comment: @ Jon Yes, sorry, just saw that after the comments updated. I still think it is still a good idea to output the column names to see.